# Color spaces conversions

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program that after the user inputs an image, he could see some small image processing. More specific, I want to convert an image from RGB to CMYK and YUV and then show on screen only one component from those color spaces(i.e. only cyan from CMY or U from YUV).
I managed to implement a conversion, but at the moment I want to create a bitmap with the desired component I get stuck, as I don't know how to do it. Which channel from RGB corresponds to which CMYK/YUV component?Or am I just wrong and there is no correspondence?

Thanks!

Comment: I really can help you but first, how much experience with image processing do you have? Are you aware of CMYK profiles for specific devices? Will you compare your color result to a tool like photoshop?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I don't have that much image processing experience...but what i want is to show on a c# form a bitmap with only one channel form a specific color space and nothing more

Comment: Check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4488/XCmyk-CMYK-to-RGB-Calculator-with-source-code. I am pretty sure it will clarify what you need to perform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct correspondence between RGB and CMYK or YUV, that said there are clearly conversions. You can choose to manipulate the image in the desired color space before converting it back to RGB for display. So it would be possible to isolate a specific channel in say CMYK, copy that channel to a new image and then convert that to RGB for display.

Comment: Thanks for the input,but still my problem is that I can't see how to create a new image with only one channel from a color space.

Comment: I've done this exact thing with Windows Imaging Component, which is the native library that underlies the WPF imaging code but I've never done it from C#, it looks like if you create a `WriteableBitmap` from a clone of your converted bitmap you might be able to edit the bitmap directly...